# Different look and feel of java application from the look and feel of Operating System

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I've been asked to modify a java desktop application (I've never worked on java desktop application).

I have been gaven the project that I opened with **Netbeans 8.0.2**.
Something weird happens.

If I launch the app from Netbeans (after doing "**clean and build**") with **right click on the project - > run** I get this look and feel:

[image]

If I launch the app from command line with `java -jar C:\Users\...\NetBeansProjects\Clean\appaName.jar` I get this look and feel (that is the correct one, since it is the look and feel of my OS, windows 10):

[image]

As you can see from the pics below, on Netbeans the **Runtime Platform** and **JRE** seem to be correclty set.

[image]
[image]
Does anybody know why? Be patience, I've never worked on desktop aplication.

Thank you

Comment: It could be that the runner in NetBeans is using a different JRE to the on on your machine, which may have a different Look and Feel configured.

Comment: How can I select on Netbeans the same JRE on my machine (on my machine I have JDK 1.8)

Comment: What is “SO” term?

Comment: Not used NetBeans, but there should be some menu option that allows you to configure how you run a Java application, it should allow you to choose JRE, and set other command line options.  Another possibility is that the runner might be picking up NetBeans look and feel so you might have to change the look and feel for NetBeans itself

Comment: @BasilBourque sorry, I made a mistake. I mean Operating System (Windows 10)

Comment: @MDP You can edit the title and body of your Question, to fix the typo. And always define your terms and abbreviations.

Comment: @BasilBourque you are right. I edited my post

Comment: @Gavin, I added more pics to show my settings. they seem to be correct

Comment: @MDP as far as I can tell they look correct; If there is a preference panel for NetBeans itself see if it has an option to change NetBeans Look and Feel.  Failing that download a different IDE and see if you get the same result.

Comment: @Gavin, thank you for your help, i'll follow your advice.
According to your experience, is it possible that among the project files there is a file that sets the look and feel only when the app is running under the IDE?

Comment: @MDP its been a very long time since I worked with Java UI's so a lot might have changed.  That said I have never been aware of being able to set a different look and feel for different IDE's.  If I was a betting man I would say its picking up NetBeans' look and feel as the screen shots don't look like a windows UI to me.

Comment: @Gavin, I launch the app with Spring tool suite and the look and feel is correct.
It is probably a specific problem of Netbeans 8.0.2. Thank you for your precious help.

Comment: @MDP you're welcome.  Check Joop Eggens answer below it would probably be best to set the look and feel to the one you want; just remember that "system look and feel" means you will get the one tailored to the OS.

Comment: @Gavin In my class I already have the code Joop Eggen suggests

Comment: All the evidence is pointing to NetBeans then... I would use IntelliJ if I were you ;)

Answer (score 3):

Initialize the look & feel to the System one. (Though I like "Nimbus" more.)

This should best be done in the beginning.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
    ...
}
```

Look in the NetBeans generated code for a `main`; as look&feel code might well be generated too.

Comment: Thank you for your help man, but I already have this code in my class

Comment: Do you start that main in the IDE (see setting of main class, or try run the main class)?

Comment: Yes Joop Eggen, I tried to run the main class (right click on the main class -> run file). Anyway, I can see that on Netbeans, the main class is the correctly set (right click on the project -> properties -> run -> Main class field).

Anyway, if I create a new project Netbeans shows the correct look and feel.
I have this problem just with this project, created by someone else.

Comment: And you probably already did a global search for `setLookAndFeel`, though it looks more like some setting. Create a new project and copy only the sources, in case it are project settings.

Comment: Its seems to be a general problem related to this project + netbeans. If I edit the code and then I run the project the changes are not applied (included the ones about look and feel). If I build the project and then I run the just created file (project/dist/filename.jar) the changes are applied. This weird behaviour happens only if I edit this project on Netbeans. If I edit this project with Eclipse I'm able to see the changes (even the ones about look and feel) and I'm able to see the changes also on my own projects created on Netbeans.

Comment: I have worked with Eclipse, IntelliJ and NetBeans. NetBeans is fine and easier than eclipse. Maybe switch to a **maven** project inside NetBeans, my favorite infrastructure. Then it is largely independent from NetBeans artifacts. But comes with dependency (=library) management. I had hoped an other answer whould show up.